# How to quickly add quotes and commas to a list of items for c() in R?

Tags: r

This is a matter of convenience more than anything.  I'm often adding quotes and commas by hand to make a c() list for some other function.  Is there a quick and clever way to add them that doesn't involve tricky find/replaces or multiple operations?  If I have multiple items separated by a space or tab, or one item per line I'd like to do the following:

A B C D

or

A

B

C

D

to:

```
temp <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

I can add them by hand, do a find/replace for the whitespace to ", " and then add in the first/last, but that is annoying.  Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Try with `dput(v1)`

Comment: Looking at this a year later I'm realizing that the request to "add commas" should have been seen as an opportunity for education. There are no commas in the `temp` result above. Rather, the commas are added by the `print` function to signify that the values are considered as character-type.

Answer (score 10):

The `scan` function is the basis for all the `read.*` functions, but it also serves to execute the task you desire executed. A couple of years ago a `text` parameter was added so you no longer need to wrap `textConnection` around "naked strings". Can be used with any delimiter and the default whitespace delimiter will handle what yopu ask to be processed:

```
 TEMP <- scan(text="A B C D", what="")

#-------------------
Read 4 items
> TEMP
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> dput(TEMP)
c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

If you need to maintain leading zeros on what might be numeric, then you will need to either import them as text or prepend the leading zeros when printing them with `formatC` or `sprintf`

Comment: This solved the issue of copying 100's of column names from excel and renaming a data.frame in R immediately (I had to load the data from a .dbf to keep leading 0's, which truncated the column names).

Comment: `scan` can be a very useful function. It's the basis for read.table and derivatives, but sometimes you need to "roll your own" input functions so using a mixture of `readLines`, `scan` and `gsub` can get you out of complex situations that the `read.*` functions cannot handle.

Answer (score 6):

Here are options for both base R string functions and for `stringr` ones. In both cases, the idea is to split the text at each space, then replace word boundaries with a single quote (`'`). The reason for doing this is to differentiate from the double quotes (`"`) that start and end a string, i.e. to have quotation marks within a string. You should be able to do the same thing by escaping double quotes (`\\"`), but I find I rarely match them up properly when I try to do this, so I didn't test it. Then you collapse that vector of strings back together by commas (could also be a comma followed by a space).

With base functions:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
txt <- "A B C D"

split_txt <- strsplit(txt, split = "\\s")[[1]]

quoted <- gsub("\\b", "'", split_txt)

paste(quoted, collapse = ",")
#> [1] "'A','B','C','D'"
```

Or tidyverse ones:

```r
txt %>%
  str_split("\\s") %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  str_replace_all("\\b", "'") %>%
  str_flatten(collapse = ",")
#> [1] "'A','B','C','D'"
```

Answer (score 5):

Even though it's a bit tricky, you can create and use *multiple cursors* within RStudio.

Multiple cursors can be created in a variety of ways:

Press Ctrl + Alt + {Up/Down} to create a new cursor in the pressed direction,

Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + {Direction} to move a second cursor in the specified 
direction,

Use Alt and drag with the mouse to create a rectangular selection,

Use Alt + Shift and click to create a rectangular selection from the current cursor position to the clicked position.

Taken from [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/05/06/rstudio-v0-99-preview-more-editor-enhancements/) and gif of how it looks like: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [typeStringsGadget](https://github.com/daranzolin/typeStringsGadget) RStudio Addin. It does exactly what you want, see the use case below.

[image: typeStringsGadget example]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the datapasta addin.

```
install.packages("datapasta")
```

Then go to Tools -> AddIns and search for datapasta. You'll see all of the options for Paste. You can paste as data a data frame, paste as a vector, etc.